# Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html.parser. Do you need to install a parser library?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-lambda

I'm developing some code for a lambda on AWS.

```
# import libraries
import urllib.request as urllib2
from Packages.bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import Packages.requests as requests
import json

def run(event, context):

    try:

        # specify the url
        quote_page = 'http://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/index.html';

        page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        tickers = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'wsod_symbol'})

        # api end point http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/TopStock/

        for i in range(13,23):

            url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/TopStock/'

            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

            data = {
                "ticker": tickers[i].text,
                "date": str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
            }
            response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

            print(response.text)

            print( data )

        return dict(statusCode=200, body='working')
    except Exception as e:
        return dict(statusCode=500, body=str(e))

print(run(0,0))
```

It runs fine on my env manage by anaconda.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I have exported the packages and running it from in the project

```
from Packages.bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

but I'm getting this issue

> Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested:
>   html.parser. Do you need to install a parser library?

I have tried

- pip install --upgrade lxml
- brew install libxslt1-dev libxml2 python-dev

Can't get it to work :(

> running python 3.5

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem while developing code for Lambda as well. I am using a deployment package so that my project directory looks like this:
[my Lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9DWN.png)

`vendors/bs4/builder/__init__.py` has a hardcoded reference `this_module = sys.modules['bs4.builder']`

1. I changed this to `this_module = sys.modules['vendors.bs4.builder']`
   where `vendors` is the name of my directory for 3rd party packages
2. I also prepended `vendors.` to the `bs4` imports in
       `bs4/builder/_htmlparser`. Take care to change the imports if you're using a different parser like `lxml` or `html5lib`

If you use something like [Apex](https://apex.run/) you can add these two commands to your build hook in `function.json` to automate the steps above.

- `sed -i -e 's/bs4.builder/vendors.bs4.builder/g'
     ./vendors/bs4/builder/__init__.py`
- `sed -i -e 's/bs4./vendors.bs4./g' ./vendors/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py`

Comment: This problem solved the initial parsing error, however, I encountered some import errors further on. What ultimately solved the problem for me was to install all dependencies in the project root, not a directory like vendors/. This no longer requires replacing text in bs4. It's makes everything a bit messy, but it works.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I did enjoy seeing the comment `bs4.builder`: *I'm fairly sure this is not the best way to do this.*.  Whatever the right way is - I'm inclined to agree with this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a deployment package for AWS Lambda as described here in their docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html.

On your local environment, anaconda takes care of setting up all your packages. On AWS however external packages like `BeautifulSoup` can be called only if they are present in the deployment package.

Comment: It's not Beautiful soup that's missing It seems to be html.parser installed? How do you connect to  html.parser when its not a package but still a dependency.

Comment: That's great. In the future if youre using imports not from the standard library, it would make more sense to create a deployment package. If you work with a lot of Lambda functions, Gordon is a great tool. https://github.com/jorgebastida/gordon